# Having trouble querying some data from the firestore (react)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Security role in fireStore like this

```
 allow read: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
```

and I am trying to git the data like this

```
export function GetPatients(limit) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("patients")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .collection("patient")
      .orderBy("creation", "desc")
      .where("uid", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid && "importent" ,"==" ,true)
      .limit(limit)
      .onSnapshot((result) => {
        let Patients = result.docs.map((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          const id = doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
        lastPatient = result.docs[result.docs.length - 1];
        dispatch({ type: GET_PATIENTS, Patients });
      });
  };
}
```

do I need to change the roles or there is something wrong with how a querying the data ?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to query for, how you are querying it, and what you expect. Share all the related code that you can. Thank you :)

Comment: I am trying to get all the patient that are important I edited the question I hop it will help

Comment: 1) Don't just give us a single line of rules to go on please. Instead edit your question to include the [minimal *complete*/standalone rules with which anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) The same applies for your code: we have no way to know what happens when you `dispatch()` or if your `onSnapshot` callback even gets called. If you `console.log()` something that shows the problem instead, you can show the output in your question and it's more likely we'll be able to help (or try an reproduce the problem on our own systems).

Comment: this is the error I get Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: forget about what i am trying to git now if i wont to get the data with the name something how can i go about it and don't forget there is "uid", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid to... what should I change in my roles

Comment: in short I am to do multiple query in one api call how can I do that